# Read fixed bytes from Tcp Stream Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code receiving a file from a tcp socket (improvements are welcome, it's a little bit slow).
I would need to send the filename in the first X bytes of the packet. How can I read a certain number of bytes?

```
Future<void> handleClient(Socket client) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    if (!await directory.exists()) {
      await directory.create();
    }

    String appDocPath = directory.path;
    var file = File('$appDocPath/1_received.mp4');

    if (file.existsSync()) {
      file.deleteSync();
    }

    client.listen((data) {
      file.writeAsBytesSync(data, mode: FileMode.append);
    }, onDone: () async {
      await client.close();

      service.invoke(
        'new_video_received',
        {
          "file": file.path,
        },
      );
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("error $error");
    });
  }

  ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, dataPort.value)
      .then((ServerSocket server) {
    server.listen(handleClient);
  });
```

In kotlin I was able to send the filename in the first 512 bytes and cut the empty bytes to get the string.

Comment: The only way you can read from a socket is by listening to it, leaving you no control over how the boundaries of the incoming blocks get delivered. There are classes like https://pub.dev/documentation/buffer/latest/buffer/ByteDataReader-class.html which let you buffer those arbitrary chunks of bytes and consume them gradually. Just add the incoming bytes to the the buffer and you can then read them in batches of your choosing.

Comment: for reading data chunks from a stream use [ChunkedStreamReader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html) and for writing the file check `Stream.pipe` method - the docs say: "Pipes the events of this stream into streamConsumer. All events of this stream are added to streamConsumer using StreamConsumer.addStream. The streamConsumer is closed when this stream has been successfully added to it - when the future returned by addStream completes without an error. Returns a future which completes when this stream has been consumed and the consumer has been closed"

Comment: what `controller1` do you mean?

Comment: (I have edited my comment, controller1 was a StreamController() ) Thanks for your reply. I am not sure how to use ChunkedStreamReader and the pipe method together. Now I have the client stream directly in Fileio: var fileio = file.openWrite(); await fileio.addStream(client); but I need to take the first 512 byte and then write the remaining bytes to the file.

Comment: `ChunkedStreamReader` has `getChunk` and `getStream` methods, use the first for getting the fixed "header" and the second to pipe the rest of the stream to the file sink

Comment: I can't see getStream in [ChunkedStreamReader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html) what am I doing wrong?

Comment: oops, sorry it was a typo

Comment: I can see only readStream ( but I have to pass the byte size ). How can I pass the rest of stream to File ? Can I use directly the socket stream ?

Comment: pass any huge size you want: for example 0xffffffff, but actually why don't you use httpserver instead serversocket? With that you could pass a filename in http custom header

Comment: Thanks. Yes, actually it's a good idea. I Will give a try